# How should I build a control array using html, jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've little more than basic knowledge of the html-php-jquery-ajax combination but I'm a long time at VB. I can best describe what I'm attempting to do in VB terms but I need to do it with in a html/php page that already uses jQuery, ajax and interfaces with php.

I'm querying a db and returning id & description. I want to dynamically build a control array that will represent the returned data.

This function calls the db read from a button onclick event...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadio(){
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/db/loadio.php", type: "POST", datatype: "html"
        }); //request   
        request.done(function(result) { 
            $('#status').html("Result: " + result );
        });  //request.done
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            $('#status').html("Request failed: " + textStatus + " " + jqXHR.status );
            }); //request.fail
    }; //loadio
</script>
```

It calls to and returns data from this php file...

```
<?php
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbtable');
        $stmt = $con->prepare('select id, description from iotable where iotype = 1');  
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $description);
        while ($stmt->fetch()){
            echo $id, $description, "<br/>";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    $con->close();
?>
```

So what I want to do is the following:
Build an array of labels that represents the returned $description, and
Build a corresponding array of buttons, somehow assigning the #id, so that when clicked they can use the #id as a variable that can be passed to a common function 
(e.g. alert("Button " + #id + " was clicked");).

If I had to do this in .NET I'd create a class with the controls and events within it and simply create new instances of the class as required, storing all the required variables within that instance.

So here's my question:
How should I be going about this using html, php, jQuery, ajax?
Can I create dynamic control arrays?
Do I need to be considering a completely different approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you got to do is to fill an array with php and then to send it back in JSON format :

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json'); //we tell the browser that we are going to send json
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbtable');
    $stmt = $con->prepare('select id, description from iotable where iotype = 1');  
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $description);
    $results = array(); //array declaration
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $results[$id] = $description; //associative array : key = id, value = description
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();
    echo json_encode($results); //we send (ie print) json-encoded array $results
    exit(); //not mandatory, just to precise that the script has to stop here
?>
```

Then you will receive json array in javascript, you can decode it and loop on it, for example :

```
request.done(function(result) { 
    var results =  $.parseJSON(result);
    $.each(results, function(){
        //create here your buttons
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier. I'll give that a go. Does that limit scope to add other variables? For example, lets say I go to id, description, type, etc,

Comment: Then, the best solution would be to create a PHP class describing the data you get back from database. Then you instantiate this class for each row you get, and you put all your objects into the result array. You decode it the same way and you will got an array of javascript objects that you can use as is.

Comment: @Arius007 Any news about it ?

Comment: Olivier, I've tried that and several amendments to it, but as yet I haven't gotten it working. $.parseJSON($results) wasn't working at all (seemed to be causing an error that prevented the function completing) but json_decode(result) seemed to do something i.e. it was letting the function run. I hope to get back to it again tomorrow.

Comment: The first segment is working fine. It's building the array and I've viewed the array to verify this. The problem at this stage is that I don't know how to access the returned data correctly. I call the data with this, but I don't know what var should contain the result:  [code] var request = $.ajax({
   url: "/db/loaddata3.php", type: "POST", datatype: "json", data: str
  });
  request.done(function(result) {file_put_contents('php://stderr', print_r(result, TRUE)); }); [/code] I'm trying to read result as a variable but it's not working.